# Using Jasmine's done() to do asynchronous testing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am attempting to test some asynchronous JavaScript (that was once TypeScript) using Jasmine. I've had a hard time getting this to work correctly, and with this simple example it never makes it to the `then(function(` code block and I get the following error:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

My test looks something like:

```
it("Should work", function(done){
    dataService.ready = true;
    dataService.isReady().then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        expect(result).toBe(true);
        done();
    });
});
```

And the service I'm testing looks something like (before compiled to JavaScript):

```
public isReady(): angular.IPromise<any> {

   var deferred = this.q.defer();

   if (this.ready) {
       setTimeout(() => { return deferred.resolve(true); }, 1);
   } else {
       // a bunch of other stuff that eventually returns a promise
   }

   return deferred.promise;
}
```

I am sure I am just misusing `done()` but I feel like this should work! Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE:**

For further debugging, I added a few console logs within the `isReady()` function. It now looks like:

```
public isReady(): angular.IPromise<any> {

   var deferred = this.q.defer();
   console.log("in isReady()"); // new line to add logging

   if (this.ready) {
       console.log("this.ready is true"); // new line to add logging
       setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("returning deferred.resolve"); // new line to add logging
            return deferred.resolve(true);
       }, 1);
   } else {
       // a bunch of other stuff that eventually returns a promise
   }

   return deferred.promise;
}
```

`isReady()` works as expected when I manually test in a browser. When running the test, my logs include:

```
LOG: 'in isReady()'
LOG: 'this.ready is true'
LOG: 'returning deferred.resolve'
```

Within my test, it appears to never be resolved (code block within `then()` is never executed) but when running my app this function works just fine. This example is in a controller:

```
DataService.isReady().then(() => {
   console.log("I work!");
});
```

---

**UPDATE: And more debugging...**

In my test:

```
it("Should work", function(done){
    console.log("calling dataService.isReady()");
    var prom = dataService.isReady();

    console.log("promise before");
    console.log(prom);

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("promise after");
        console.log(prom);
     },1000);

     prom.then(function(result){
         // never makes it here
         done();
     }, function(reason) {
        // never makes it here either
     });
}
```

Now, in my console, I see:

```
LOG: 'calling dataService.isReady()'
LOG: 'in isReady()'
LOG: 'this.ready is true'
LOG: 'promise before'
LOG: Object{$$state: Object{status: 0}}
LOG: 'returning deferred.resolve'
LOG: 'promise after'
LOG: Object{$$state: Object{status: 1, pending: [...], value: true, processScheduled: true}}
```

So, my promise looks like it should. Why isn't `then()` being invoked?

Comment: From a quick look at the assertion function it should work. I would debug `isReady` itself to see if it is working as expected.

Comment: Hi Jason! Thanks for the comment. I updated the question to add a few more debugging details around `isReady`

Comment: Have you tried using the `$q` constructor syntax instead of `defer`?
`return $q((resolve, reject) => { ... })`

Comment: @Freyday : I ended up with the same results, successful/as expected behavior, but the test throws the same timeout error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What was actually happening:**
So, it turns out my question should have been something like "Why doesn't my angular promise resolve in my Jasmine test?"

---

#### $digest

After a bit of digging and looking at other solutions, I found some good information about when/how promises are resolved. I needed to call `$digest()` on the `$rootScope` in order to resolve the promise and execute the `then()` code block (and therefore call `done()` to satisfy the spec).

#### No more request expected error

Adding `$rootScope.$digest()` got me *most* of the way there, but then I started discovering a `No more request expected` error that was causing my tests to fail. This was because the service I am using is sending off various `POST` and `GET` requests for another aspect of my application. Stubbing out a `whenGET` and `whenPOST` response seemed to solve that issue.

---

### The Final Solution:

Long story short, my spec file now looks like:

```
describe("Async Tests", function(){

    var dataService;
    var rootScope;
    var httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module("myangularapp"));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _DataService_, $rootScope){

        dataService = _DataService_;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        // solves the 'No more request expected' errors:
        httpBackend.whenGET('').respond([]);
        httpBackend.whenPOST('').respond([]);

    }));

    it("Should work", function(done){

        dataService.ready = true;

        dataService.isReady().then(function(result){

            console.log(result);
            expect(result).toBe(true);

            // still calls done() just as before
            done();

        });

        // digest the scope every so often so we can resolve the promise from the DataService isReady() function
        setInterval(rootScope.$digest, 100);

    });

});
```

This solution seems more complex than it needs to be, but I think it'll do the trick for now. I hope this helps anyone else who may run into challenges with testing async code with Angular and Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this is to always use `.finally(done)` when testing promises and then call `$timeout.flush()` afterwards.

```
"use strict";

describe('Services', function() {
  var $q;
  var $timeout;

  // Include your module
  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  // When Angular is under test it provides altered names
  // for services so that they don't interfere with
  // outer scope variables like we initialized above.
  // This is nice because it allows for you to use $q
  // in your test instead of having to use _q , $q_ or 
  // some other slightly mangled form of the original
  // service names
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$q_, _$timeout_) {
    $q = _$q_;

    // *** Use angular's timeout, not window.setTimeout() ***
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
  }));

  it('should run DataService.isReady', function(done) {

    // Create a Dataservice
    function  DataService() {}

    // Set up the prototype function isReady
    DataService.prototype.isReady = function () {

      // Keep a reference to this for child scopes
      var _this = this;

      // Create a deferred
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // If we're ready, start a timeout that will eventually resolve
      if (this.ready) {
        $timeout(function () {

          // *** Note, we're not returning anything so we
          // removed 'return' here. Just calling is needed. ***
          deferred.resolve(true);
        }, 1);
      } else {
        // a bunch of other stuff that eventually returns a promise
        deferred.reject(false);
      }

      // Return the promise now, it will be resolved or rejected in the future
      return deferred.promise;
    };

    // Create an instance
    var ds = new DataService();
    ds.ready = true;

    console.log('got here');

    // Call isReady on this instance
    var prom = ds.isReady();
    console.log(prom.then);

    prom.then(function(result) {
     console.log("I work!");
     expect(result).toBe(true);
    },function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }, function() {
      console.log('progress?');
    })

    // *** IMPORTANT: done must be called after promise is resolved
    .finally(done);
    $timeout.flush(); // Force digest cycle to resolve promises;
  });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LFp214GQcm97Kyv8xnLp